# Permissions over publishing pages

Tags: permissions, publishing-page

What should be the level permissions to see a publishing page on a site?
I've tried with restricted readers and read and I cannot see the publishing pages, how that works?

Comment: Restricted readers should be able to view the page so long as it is published and approved and any related assets are checked in as majjor versions, published, and approved, like CSS, Images, even the page layout itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that page has been published at least once. Without a published version, nobody can see the page unless you have created the page.

By the way, here is a complete guide to SharePoint Permissions:
[User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx)

hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Totally my mistake but thanks :)